# Not sure whether to use arrays / lists / collections / or other to store my data

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, data-structures, collections

I am rather confused as to what type of class to hold my data. I have done research on the various classes but am still unsure what suits my application best...

I am writing a self-tester that offers questions to the user that must be answered. There are four types of questions. I generate a random number between 0-49 and then use that number to pick the question.

Currently, I have all the question data stored in an multi-dimensional array. This works fine seeing there are currently only 50 questions. Once the question is displayed, I add that question's number to a pool so it is not asked twice.

I am aware that there is unnecessary processing involved in always checking the used-question pool, considering the program can make multiple checks depending on what random number is rolled - SOOO here I finally get to my question.... :)

I want to be able to add and remove questions easily to this list of data - something not possible in an array (efficient removal anyways). Collections don't seem to be quite what I need, so I'm thinking a List would be the way to go..? If so how would I add my data to the list and perform all the functions I need? (iteration, add/remove etc).

Here's current example of a question in my array. There will potentially be thousands of these:

```
questionPool1(1, 0) = "What is the expansion of: ADF"
questionPool1(1, 1) = "AUTOMATIC DIRECTION FINDER"
questionPool1(1, 2) = "An automatic direction finder (ADF) is a device for finding the direction to a radio source."
questionPool1(1, 3) = "Abbreviations"
questionPool1(1, 4) = "Medium"
questionPool1(1, 5) = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_direction_finder"
```

Any advice to put me on the right track would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Why not put these data in a database table?

Comment: Thanks Rachcha. I considered databases but I chose to store questions in a module so I can plug in any other modules in the future. Maybe databases are the go... ?

Comment: One big advantage is that the data is saved permanently. Next, you don't have to worry much about the position of elements, array indexes getting out of bounds, looping/iterating and lots more. This depends upon the volume of your data. If it's large, store it in a DB. If small enough, store it in an application pool- an instance which is shared by all sessions.

Comment: If I was you and there were thousands of questions like those, I'd definitely put those in a database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the database suggestion, or an XML file.  Each row would be an entry, each column would be the Question Answer, Wiki etc.

As to the actual question, arrays are old school, and the alternatives you mentioned are a better choice.  But they rarely work alone:

```
Class QandA
   Public Property Question
   Public Property Answer
   Public Property LongAnswer
   Public Property Abbreviation
   Public Property NumberFour
   Public Property MoreInfo
End Class

Friend _QA As List(Of QandA)

' display:
txtQuestion.Text = _QA(randomIndex).Question

txtWiki.Text = _QA(randomIndex).MoreInfo
```

Notice how the container organizes the code for you?  No more recalling that 0 is the Q and one is the A - it is spelled out for you, and when you come back to the code 3 months later, it will still make sense.

To add an item:

```
Dim QA As New QandA
With QA
    .Question = "....."
    .Answer = "....."
   ' etc
End With

_QA.Add(QA)
```

A database will provide an almost as nice container.  With a list, you could store the data in a text file and load the List in a loop if you wanted to hold off on DB stuff for a while.  You could also split the difference: have the master list in a text file which you only reload when it changes, then serialize the List and load from that as a matter of normal course.  Depends on how it is used, really.

Comment: Thanks Plutonix. Yes, I think I like this approach. How would I actually add the data to those fields though? would it still be possible to pull the data from a module? Sorry for newb questions.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the thorough response :)